# Can I erase a missing device to iCloud after removing it from My Devices?

Tags: icloud, iphone, find-my-iphone, secure-erase

I had to return a dead iPhone to my phone carrier, so I needed to 1) erase the phone, and 2) remove it from the Find My iPhone app on my iCloud account. The phone is still in my possession for a day or two, but I cannot get it to charge and the battery has no juice.

Since the phone won't turn on, I needed to perform those two steps on iCloud.com rather than on my phone.

Unfortunately, I accidentally Removed the phone before Erasing it. :-(

As a result, I no longer can see it in my list of devices in the Find My iPhone app on iCloud.com. However, in the Settings app, it lists that phone as one of my iDevices running either iOS 8, Yosemite, or WatchOS.

Is there any way I can still schedule an erase for the iPhone if/when it comes alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid since the device is removed from Find my iPhone app you can no longer make changes from iCloud.com. If you would be able to start the device again - sometimes you don't even need to go all the way as fully booted system - it will reappear in the Find my iPhone app.

I work at a retail chain as a service agent and have seen this many times. Customers wanting to leave their phone for repair/replacement, have removed the unit from iCloud.com but not erased it - simply starting it will reactivate the Find my iPhone and remote erase is available again.

Hope you get any way to start the device - even if it's not a fully booted system.